# How to prevent VLC from opening a window that is too big?

Tags: vlc-media-player, media-player

Sometimes VLC may open a small window. But sometimes it will open a window that is like 90% of the entire screen making clicking the controls very hard.

Is there a way to set a consistent size for VLC to always open in?

Comment: @RogUE - sorry, I just trashed my answer, as it was about as wrong as it could get ;) & just flagged as a dupe instead. At a certain rep you can still see deleted posts, though idk at what point that kicks in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to customize the size of window, you may try to oen up Tools > Preferences. Then you could configure settings in the "Interface" section.